# Change php modules directory

Tags: linux, php

I am compiling php, and its setting my modules directory to /usr/lib64/20090626-zts

I would like to change this to /usr/lib64/php/modules, but I cannot find a configuration option to do so.

I can change it in my php.ini and move the directory, but when I run phpize and make a new module it still puts it in /usr/lib64/20090626-zts

Comment: Haven't have time to test this: `EXTENSION_DIR=/usr/lib64/php/modules phpize`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest making /usr/lib64/php/modules a symlink to the folder with the ID. This prevents mixing extensions from different versions of PHP in the long run.

Besides that: You should be able to set it by setting `EXTENSION_DIR` as environment variable before running PHP's configure. something like

```
 $ EXTENSION_DIR=/my/location ./configure --with-some-extension
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I don't want my modules to conflict in the future.  I think I will just leave the folder name alone.

Answer (score 8):

Check the current extension directory with:

```
php-config --extension-dir
```

and you can change it by setting `extension_dir` in `php.ini`:

```
extension_dir="/usr/lib64/php/modules"
```

Don't forget to restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was not identical, but since this question was the first to pop up with answers that were ultimately very helpful, I will add my comments.

I was having trouble getting PHP (under Centos7 running in a docker container) to use MySQL due to directory configuration - although I was using pre-built binaries and not compiling anything. Although the various pdo and mysqlnd.so modules and .ini files were installed in my container (just using standard `yum install php72` and all the other stuff specified in the [PHP install wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)), they were not in the default places that PHP was looking for them. I have no idea why. Maybe it's some kind of docker thing?

Anyway, to solve the issue I had to echo an `extension_dir` directive to my `PHP.ini` and ALSO set the `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` env variable. These are the relevant commands from my Dockerfile

```
ENV PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/etc/php.d/
RUN echo 'extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules"' >> /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.ini
```

I hope this doesn't result in getting module conflicts later down the track as @johanes warns.

Comment: > "they were not in the default places. "

You didn't follow the wizard instructions properly, choosing "single version", everything in installed in default places. SCL use different paths to allow multiple versions.

Comment: @RemiCollet thanks for the response. I chose single version from the wizard - which is what I think I want since I only want one version of PHP on my container. The only part of the wizard instructions that I didn't add in my dockerfile was ` yum --enablerepo=remi-php72-test install php-xxx` and `yum update`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: These latest commands are for test packages, and for additional extension (replace xxx by the name of the extension you want)

Comment: @RemiCollet Sorry, I must be a bit dumb. Are you saying that if use the test packages this will fix my problem of the mysql modules not going into the  `.../remi/...` folders?

Comment: I say that php-* packages (single version) use standard paths, and php72-php-* (SCL, multiple versions) use /opt/remi. See https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl

Comment: OK, thanks for that. Changing my install from 
`yum install php72 php-mysqlnd php-pdo php72-mod_php`
to
`yum install php php-mysqlnd php-pdo php-mod_php
`
Did the trick. I was mixing my install up. Thanks for your patience.